# Web.config transformation does not take web.debug.config but uses default

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web.config-transform

`dotnet publish` seems not to take the existing `web.debug.config`.

Steps

- Created a new project in VS 2022 (17.6.2), using 'ASP .NET Core Web API' as project template.
- Did a `dotnet publish` from CLI and grabbed the default `web.config` from publish folder.
- Then added a `web.debug.config` with same content as the default to the project root.
- Within `web.debug.config`, added timeout value `<aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:02:00" ...`.
- When I do a `dotnet publish` again, the `web.debug.config` gets copied to the publish folder, default `web.config` is still there.
- I would expect that there is a `web.config` with the content from my own `web.debug.config`.

I have played around with `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>` and `<CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>` resulting the file beeing copied or not, but without effect on the actual content of `web.config`.

What am I missing or is my expectation among Transforming Web.config wrong?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption was wrong:
a `web.debug.config` does not *replace* the `web.config` but *transform* it using the  `xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"` namespace and later its `Locator` and `Transform` attributes.